# Display subcategories and add classess to lists during recurion in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I am using recursion function to display categories and subcategories in PHP.
In MySQL database table, there are 3 columns:

```
cat_id, parent_id, cat_name
```

However, I should keep tracking of unordered lists in order to add class to make a drop down menu using jQuery. So, the HTML code should look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class = "dropdown"><a href = "#">Parent 1</a>
        <ul class = "sub-menu">
            <li><a href = "#">Sub 1</a></li>
            <li class = "dropdown">
                <a href = "#">Sub 2</a>
                <ul class = "sub-menu">
                    <li><a href = "#">Sub 2.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Sub 2.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Sub 2.3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href = "#">Sub 3</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Sub 4</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Sub 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href = "#">Parent 2</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Parent 3</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Parent 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

The recursion function that I am using:

```
$query = "select * from  categories";$result = $conn->query($query); $cats = array();while($cat = $result->fetch_assoc()){$cats_ID[$cat['cat_id']][] = $cat;$cats[$cat['parent_id']][$cat['cat_id']] = $cat;}

function build_tree($cats,$cat_id,$only_parent = false){
    if(is_array($cats) and isset($cats[$cat_id])){
        $tree = "<ul>\n";

        if($only_parent==false){
            foreach($cats[$cat_id] as $cat){
                $tree .= '<li><a href = "#">'.$cat['cat_name'];
                $tree .=  build_tree($cats,$cat['cat_id']);
                $tree .= "</a></li>\n";
            }
        }

        $tree .= "</ul>";        
    }
    else return null;

    return $tree;
}
```

How can i keep track of ul lists?

Comment: The question you're asking is incredibly broad. We'll need more details in order to begin helping you.

Comment: In your recursive function, add a `$depth` argument that defaults to `1`. Then on each recurse, pass in `$depth+1`. This will track your "depth" in the recursion. Each time you recurse down again, that will increase. Then, if `$depth` is greater than `1`, you know you are in a sub-menu and add your class. You could even put an attribute on the element with it's depth in case you need it in JS. Other than that, you would need to share the recursion code if you want it modified.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn edited the question

Comment: @TimothyR edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it like I suggested in the comment above by adding a `$depth` parameter.

```
$query = "select * from  categories";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$cats = array();
while($cat = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $cats_ID[$cat['cat_id']][] = $cat;
    $cats[$cat['parent_id']][$cat['cat_id']] = $cat;
}

//added a depth argument that defaults to 1
function build_tree($cats,$cat_id,$only_parent = false, $depth=1){
    if(is_array($cats) and isset($cats[$cat_id])){
        //check if depth is > 1, output class, else, no class.
        if($depth > 1){
            $tree = "<ul class='sub-menu'>\n";
        } else {
            $tree = "<ul>\n";
        }

        if($only_parent==false){
            foreach($cats[$cat_id] as $cat){
                //get the recursion first
                //adjusted recursive call to include depth+1.
                $tmp =  build_tree($cats,$cat['cat_id'],$only_parent,$depth+1);

                //if we are at the first depth and there is child content
                if($depth == 1 && is_null($tmp)){
                    //add the dropdown class
                    $tree .= '<li class="dropdown"><a href = "#">'.$cat['cat_name'];
                } else {
                    //no dropdown class
                    $tree .= '<li><a href = "#">'.$cat['cat_name'];
                }
                //now append the recursion
                $tree .=  $tmp;
                $tree .= "</a></li>\n";
            }
        }
        $tree .= "</ul>";        
    }
    else return null;
    return $tree;
}
```

You should be able to just replace your function with this new one and everything should just work since the newly added argument has a default value.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: One more question... How can i add a class to list element? You can see it in HTML code above

Comment: @AibolOrazbekov updated again, this time to correctly calculate where the dropdowns are needed.